# If a locally euclidean topological space $X$ is connected, then $X$ is locally $n$-euclidean and we can define its dimension

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

**Def**. A topological space $X$ is *locally euclidean* iff  $\forall x\in X$, $\exists U$ an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ such that $U\cong_{hom} D^n$ (where $D^n$ is the $n$-dimensional ball) for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Def**. A topological space $X$ is *locally $n$-euclidean* iff  $\forall x\in X$, $\exists U$ an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ such that $U\cong_{hom} D^n$ (where $D^n$ is the $n$-dimensional ball).

**Theorem.** Let $X$ a locally euclidean topological space. The subset

$M_n=\{x\in X\quad |\quad \exists U\in \mathcal{N}(x), \quad U\cong_{hom} D^n\}$

(where $\mathcal{N}(x)$ denotes the family of all open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$) is a clopen subset of $X$.

*Proof*. First, we show that $M_n$ is an open set in $X, \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. If $M_n=\emptyset$, there's nothing to prove. Let $x\in M_n$. Then, exists $U$ an open neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ sucht that $U\cong_{hom} D^n \cong_{hom} \mathbb{R}^n$. Let's take $y\in U$. By hypothesis, $X$ is locally euclidean so, exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y\in M_m$. Then, exists $V$ an open neighbourhood of $y$ in $X$ such that $V\cong_{hom} D^m \cong_{hom} \mathbb{R}^m$. We show that $\exists V'$ an open neighbourhood of $y$ in $X$ such that $V'\subseteq U\cap V$ e $V'\cong_{hom} D^n$. Let $\varphi: V\to D^m \cong_{hom} \mathbb{R}^m$ homeomorfism. Because $U\cap V$ is open in $V$, $\varphi(U\cap V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. So, exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(\varepsilon, \varphi(y))\subseteq \varphi(U\cap V)$. Define $V'=\varphi^{-1}(B(\varepsilon, \varphi(y))$, which is open and contains $y$. So, $V'$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ in $X$. But $\varphi$ is an homeomorfism, so $B(\varepsilon, \varphi(y))\cong_{hom} V'$ and the map $V' \to U\cong_{hom} \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and injective. By Brouwer's invariance of domain theorem, we can conclude that $m\leq n$. Using the same argument, we can also exhibit $U'$ an open neighbourhood of $y$ in $X$ such that $U'\subseteq U\cap V$ e $U'\cong_{hom} D^n$ and conclude that $n\leq m$. In the end, $m=n$. Therefore, $M_n$ is an open set because is neighbourhood of every its points. On the other hand, the set  $X\setminus M_n=\bigcup_{m\ne n} M_m$ is open because it's an union of open sets, so, $M_n$ is also closed.
$\Box$

This is taken from my algebraic topology course notes. I don't understand some steps in the proof:

1. Why we choose to exhibit $V'\subseteq U\cap V$ such that $V'\cong_{hom} D^n$?
2. Why the map $V'\to U$ is continuous and injective?
3. I cannot understand why proving that $m=n$, allow us to conclude that $M_n$ is neighbourhood of all its points.

This theorem is then used to assert that if $X$ is also connected, then $X$ is locally $n$-euclidean, because $M_n=X$. And then, we define $n$ as the topological dimension of $X$.

Thanks to everyone who has the patience to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this proof is intransparent and unnessarily complicated. Here is my suggestion.

1. $M_n$ is open in $X$.

This is almost trivial. If $x \in M_n$, then there exists $U \in \mathcal N(x)$ such that $U \cong_{hom} D^n$. For all $y \in U$ we have $U \in \mathcal N(y)$, thus $U \subset M_n$.

2. $M_n \cap M_m = \emptyset$ for $n \ne m$.

Assume to the contrary that there exists  $x \in M_n \cap M_m$. Then there exist $U, V \in  \mathcal N(x)$ and homeomorphisms $\varphi : U \to D^n$ and $\psi : V \to D^m$. Since $W = U \cap V$ is an open subset of $U$, also $\varphi(W)$ is an open subset of $D^n$. We have $x \in W$, thus $\varphi(x) \in \varphi(W)$. Choose $\varepsilon  > 0$ such that $B(\varepsilon,\varphi(x)) \subset  \varphi(W)$. Then the map
$$ B(\varepsilon,\varphi(x)) \xrightarrow{\varphi^{-1}} W' = \varphi^{-1}(B(\varepsilon,\varphi(x))) \hookrightarrow W \hookrightarrow V \xrightarrow{\psi} D^m \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^m$$
is a continuous injection and we conclude $m \ge n$. Similarly we can show that $n  \ge m$. Thus $n = m$ which contradicts the assumption $n \ne m$.

3. $M_n$ is a clopen subset of $X$.

The $M_m$, $m \in \mathbb N$, partition $X$ in pairwise disjoint open sets. Since $M'_n = \bigcup_{m \ne n} M_m$ is open, we see that $M_n = X \setminus M'_n$ is closed.

4. If $X$ is connected, then the only nonempty clopen subset of $X$ is $X$ itself. This shows that $X = M_n$ for exactly one $n$. All other $M_m$ are empty.